# 'SalaryAdmin' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: django, django-admin

Hello I want to add method to list display in django admin but am getting error say SalryAdmin has no attribute request

here my admin

```
    @admin.register(Salary)
class SalaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user_name', 'action']
    
    
    def action(self, obj):
        if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            if obj.hr_state == 'request-change-approved' and self.request.user.user_role.position.code == 'HRM':
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error for obvious reason - `ModelAdmin` class does not have `request` member. Instead of this, you should mark method as action and request would be passed as an argument to the method - like so:

```py
@admin.register(Salary)
class SalaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user_name', 'action']
    actions = ['action']
    
    @admin.action(description='')
    def action(self, request, queryset):
        obj = queryset.first()  # TODO - implement object retrieval logic here

        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            if obj.hr_state == 'request-change-approved' and request.user.user_role.position.code == 'HRM':
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True
```

Here is the source to the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/actions/).